# Using ocaml OUnit2 assert_raise

Tags: ocaml, tdd

I'm going through the ray tracer challenge and I'm trying to assert that an exception is raised when adding one point to another (points have w = 1).

Basically this is what I got:

**tuple.ml**

```
type tuple = {x: float; y: float; z: float; w: float}

let point a b c =
  {x = a; y = b; z = c; w = 1.0}

exception AddingPoints of string

let (+..) a b =
  if ((a.w =. 1.0 && b.w =. 1.0) = false) 
  then raise (AddingPoints "Cannot add points")
  else 
    { 
      x = a.x +. b.x ;
      y = a.y +. b.y ;
      z = a.z +. b.z ;
      w = a.w +. b.w ;
    }
```

**tuple_test.ml**

```
open OUnit2

let p = point 4.3 (-4.2) 3.1

let test_add_point_point_should_fail = "testing adding point to point, it should fail" >::: [
  let p2 = fun () -> p +.. p in
  assert_raises (AddingPoints "Cannot add points") p2;
]
```

After running:
`ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -tag debug tuple_test.byte`

I get:

```
File "tuple_test.ml", line 41, characters 2-53:
41 |   assert_raises (AddingPoints "Cannot add points") p2;
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type
         OUnit2.test = OUnitTest.test

Command exited with code 2.
```

I'm a newbie to ocaml, can anybody tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with expression `assert_raises (AddingPoints "Cannot add points") p2`, it is more about the code around it. You're using `(>:::)` and, perhaps, trying to create a test with a label. In the docs, you can see that `val (>:::) : string -> test list -> test`, which means you should not be passing it a `unit`, which the highlighted expression is, but a `test`.

You could use `OUnit2.test_case` to create a test and use `(>:)` to create a label for it:

```
open OUnit2

let tst = OUnit2.test_case (fun _test_ctx -> assert_raises (Failure "hd") (fun () -> List.hd []));;

let tst_with_label = "extracting head of an empty list throws an exception" >: tst
```

You can also be interested in `OUnit2.test_list`, which seems like a function to compose tests.

There is quite nice docs [available](https://gildor478.github.io/ounit/ounit2/OUnit2/index.html).